# How frequent are TCAS resolution events?

Tags: safety, tcas

The question is a little open, but I'm **wondering how many TCAS resolutions (i.e. the serious type) occur every week or month over sizeable region like the United States or Europe.**

Comment: doing a search on "tcas" on [avherald](http://avherald.com/h?search_term=tcas&opt=1&dosearch=1&search.x=0&search.y=0) show quite a few

Comment: [This site](http://www.seeandavoid.org/) shows events on a map. It's hard get an idea of how often they happen but you can see the where and when.

Comment: In 4 years of flying I had many TAs but only 1 RA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a [very interesting paper](https://www.ll.mit.edu/publications/journal/pdf/vol16_no2/16_2_04Kuchar.pdf) from 2007 that analyzed TCAS performance. They analyzed recorded data to come up with 1 RA per 116 flight hours.

> Over this time period, monitoring took place for approximately 190
>   days, and roughly 200,000 Mode S flight hours were observed within the
>   sensor’s 60 nmi coverage area. We observed a total of 1725 RA events,
>   corresponding to an average of 9 RAs per day, or approximately one RA
>   every 116 flight hours.

They explain that the data was taken in the Boston area, so the high amount of traffic contributes to the high number of RAs.

[This thread](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/tech_ops/read.main/297292/) on Airliners.net suggest differently, at least in the sense that for those pilots it is a matter of a few over years, depending on where they typically fly.